# Why angular does not let me assing a value to an object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I did a query component to query one person in the database, it has a button to edit that specific person, when it is clicked it then switches to the other component to edit the person, so I added a button to return again to the query component with the updated data shown on the query component, but at the moment when it returns, the query component does not appear.

I tried to pass the data using a service this is part of the code:

```
export class PersonaGetComponent implements OnInit {

personas: Persona[];
individuo: {cedula: string, direccion: string; nombre: string; _id: string};
valor: any;

constructor(private ps: PersonasService, private vd: VolverDataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.ps
  .getPersonas()
  .subscribe((data: Persona[]) => {
   this.personas = data;
});

if (this.vd.volver === true) {
  console.log(this.individuo);
  this.valor = this.vd.cedula;
  this.individuo.cedula = this.vd.cedula;  //this part shows an error, it says that individuo is undefined so I cannot assign a value
  this.individuo.direccion = this.vd.direccion;
  this.individuo.nombre = this.vd.nombre;
 }
}
```

This is the error:

**Cannot set property 'cedula' of undefined**

The individuo object is undefined and I cannot assign any value to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had only defined the `Type` of `individuo` but never assign value to it. That why the console yelling at you that the variable is `undefined`. Do this instead:

```
// Change:
individuo: {cedula: string, direccion: string, nombre: string, _id: string};
// With this:
individuo = {cedula: '', direccion: '', nombre: '', _id: ''};
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an initial value to `individuo`, because as it says, it's `undefined`.

solution:

```
individuo: {cedula: string; direccion: string; nombre: string; _id: string} = {
    cedula: '',
    direccion: '',
    nombre: '',
    _id: ''
};
```